# what is the Faster way to compare two list or numpy arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am doing some image processing through the traversing the folders.
There is almost 1 million images and i want to check the file full name before processing whether is processed before or not.

I am keeping the processed file names in a numpy array . I am taking the full file list with below code and checking the final list with my numpy list whether is processed before .

Below code takes too long...

How can I make it faster. ?

```py
newFiles = []
duplicate = 0
old_np = np.load("FILEStest.npy") . ##//almost 200.000 

start_time = time.time()

list_of_files = bc.getListOfFiles("/Users/xxx/Downloads/CS_tt_test/")  ##// almost 1 million files. its fast . 60 sec.

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

##//Comparing here whether is already processed. This part very slow.

for old in range(len(list_of_files)):
    file = list_of_files[old]
    if not np.any(old_np[:, ] == file):
        newFiles.append(file)
    else:
        duplicate += 1
        # print("Seen before ", file)

print("duplicates : " , duplicate)

print(elapsed_time)
```

Comment: why are you using indexing instead just, for file in list_of_files ? I don't see any use of the old indexing. maybe removing it would be better, it's also more pythonic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use numpy diff:

```
diff = np.setdiff1d(full_list_np , processed_np)
```

blazingly fast...

Answer (score 2):

`set(list_of_files) - set(old_np)`

It looks like you are looking all values in `list_of_files` which are not in `old_np`. The above set operation gives that result and is pretty fast.

Sets behave different from lists. A set is unordered and can only hold unique elements. These properties allow for different operations than lists. Such operations include union and difference. More information on sets can be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

**Full code**

Short and simple

```
old_np = np.load("FILEStest.npy") . ##//almost 200.000 
list_of_files = bc.getListOfFiles("/Users/xxx/Downloads/CS_tt_test/")

new_files = set(list_of_files) - set(old_np)
```

**Timed example**

Consider the following example code. I do not know your data so this is just a dummy example.

```
%%timeit
import numpy as np

all_files = range(0, int(1e7))  # just a few more to be sure
old_files = np.random.randint(0, 1e7, size=int(1e5))  # random old "files"

new_files = set(all_files) - set(old_files)
len(new_files)
```

Returns

```
770 ms ± 29.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Not too shabby right?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, I think a more pythonic style of this block code would be like this:

```
for file in list_of_files:
    #file = list_of_files[old] # no need to use this
    if file not in old_np :
        newFiles.append(file)
    else:
        duplicate += 1
```